my project failed to register the Service Worker while adopting mocks with MSW on local and ghpages, any clues?
My folder structure:

I have these mocks:
import { http, HttpResponse, delay } from "msw";

import { Image } from "../models/image";
import { API_URL } from "../constants/environment";

const imagesList: Image[] = [
  {
    title: "Level up",
    description: "Level up",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568659358810-bdbdb4decb5c?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NHx8bmVvbnxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=60",
  },
  {
    title: "Game on",
    description: "Game on",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1546443046-ed1ce6ffd1ab?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8bmVvbnxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=60",
  },
  {
    title: "Hi",
    description: "Hi",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495069781661-dfeacdef0531?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MjB8fG5lb258ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=60",
  },
  {
    title: "Do something great",
    description: "Do something great",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504805572947-34fad45aed93?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MzR8fG5lb258ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=60",
  },
  {
    title: "Stay wired",
    description: "Stay wired",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563240381-5ccf7690ca08?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NTV8fG5lb258ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=60",
  },
  {
    title: "Do what you love",
    description: "Do what you love",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554290712-e640351074bd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NjR8fG5lb258ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=60",
  },
  {
    title: "Ready or not",
    description: "Ready or not",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581300740943-cfa5f847db2c?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NzJ8fG5lb258ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=60",
  },
  {
    title: "Pizza",
    description: "Pizza",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542587222-f9172e5eba29?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8ODR8fG5lb258ZW58MHx8MHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=60",
  },
  {
    title: "Hello",
    description: "Hello",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1520453803296-c39eabe2dab4?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTA0fHxuZW9ufGVufDB8fDB8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=60",
  },
  {
    title: "Good times",
    description: "Good times",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519608425089-7f3bfa6f6bb8?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTE4fHxuZW9ufGVufDB8fDB8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=60",
  },
  {
    title: "Make beer, not war",
    description: "Make beer, not war",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1577032229840-33197764440d?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTc5fHxuZW9ufGVufDB8fDB8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=60",
  },
  {
    title: "You're doing great",
    description: "You're doing great",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1572633424705-d813d2fb5cb4?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=2811&amp;q=80",
  },
  {
    title: "Ready or not",
    description: "Ready or not",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581300740943-cfa5f847db2c?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=750&amp;q=80",
  },
  {
    title: "Steak &amp; wine",
    description: "Steak &amp; wine",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1545464333-9cbd1f263aa0?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=750&amp;q=80",
  },
  {
    title: "We belong here",
    description: "We belong here",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1587183233478-0acdba5b184a?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1650&amp;q=80",
  },
  {
    title: "Burger",
    description: "Burger",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563191799-2c7e8c185bb3?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=750&amp;q=80",
  },
  {
    title: "Yeah",
    description: "Yeah",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1606595885348-ba270cb254d1?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1650&amp;q=80",
  },
  {
    title: "Avengers",
    description: "Avengers",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1560932684-5e552e2894e9?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mjc1fHxuZW9ufGVufDB8fDB8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=800&amp;q=60",
  },
  {
    title: "Yes",
    description: "Yes",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1584844308364-9e43f2cfaa6c?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1650&amp;q=80",
  },
  {
    title: "We believe",
    description: "We believe",
    imagePath:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1582478192200-b4bd08b40096?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=1790&amp;q=80",
  },
];

export const generateImagesList = async (): Promise<Array<Image>> => {
  return Promise.resolve(imagesList);
};

export const imagesHandlers = [
  http.get(`${API_URL}/images`, async () => {
    const images = await generateImagesList();
    return HttpResponse.json({ data: images }, { status: 200 });
  }),
  http.post(`${API_URL}/images`, async ({ request }) => {
    const data = await request.json();
    // console.log(data);
    imagesList.unshift(data as Image);
    await delay(5);
    return HttpResponse.json(data, { status: 201 });
  }),
];


this api:
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

import { Image, NewImage } from "../../models/image";
import { API_URL } from "../../constants/environment";

interface ImageResponse {
  data: Image;
}

export const imagesSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "imagesApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: API_URL }),
  tagTypes: ["Images"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    fetchImages: builder.query({
      query: () => `/images`,
      providesTags: ["Images"],
    }),
    createImage: builder.mutation<ImageResponse, NewImage>({
      query: (params) => {
        return {
          url: `${API_URL}/images`,
          method: "POST",
          body: params,
        };
      },
      invalidatesTags: ["Images"],
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useFetchImagesQuery, useCreateImageMutation } = imagesSlice;


this index.tsx
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from 'react-redux';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import store from './redux/store';
import { App } from './App';

async function enableMocking() {
  const { worker } = await import('./mocks/mocks');
  const serviceWorkerUrl = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    ? '/mockServiceWorker.js'
    : `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/mockServiceWorker.js`;

  return worker.start({
    serviceWorker: {
      url: serviceWorkerUrl
    },
    onUnhandledRequest: 'bypass'
  });
}

const rootDiv = document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement;
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootDiv);

void enableMocking().then(() => {
  root.render(
    <ReduxProvider store={store}>
      <App />
    </ReduxProvider>
  );
});


this environment.ts
export const API_URL =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
    ? "http://localhost:3000/api"
    : "https://your-production-api-url.com/api";


and this app router
import { FC } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Images } from '../components/pages/images';

const AppRouter: FC = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Images />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;


this is my package json
{
  "name": "code-challenge-test",
  "homepage": "https://mvmarco.github.io/code-challenge-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.1.3",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.6.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@storybook/theming": "^8.1.6",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.40.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.98",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.33",
    "nanoid": "^5.0.7",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.5",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.5",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.11",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "usehooks-ts": "^3.1.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "yup": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "msw": {
    "workerDirectory": [
      "public"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@chromatic-com/storybook": "^1.5.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.5",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^8.1.6",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^8.1.6",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^8.1.6",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding": "^8.1.6",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^8.1.6",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^8.1.6",
    "@storybook/react": "^8.1.6",
    "@storybook/react-webpack5": "^8.1.6",
    "@storybook/test": "^8.1.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.5",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.34",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-json": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.8.0",
    "gh-pages": "^6.1.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "msw": "^2.3.1",
    "prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.14.1",
    "storybook": "^8.1.6",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0"
  }
}


the issue is that both on github pages and on local the mocks fail, i want to use the mocks in both environment,but i keep getting this error on local and blank page on gh pages:
Uncaught runtime errors:

× ERROR [MSW] Failed to register the Service Worker:
Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope
('http://localhost:3000/') with script
('http://localhost:3000/mockServiceWorker.js'): The script has an
unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). Error: [MSW] Failed to register
the Service Worker:
Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope
('http://localhost:3000/') with script
('http://localhost:3000/mockServiceWorker.js'): The script has an
unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
at getWorkerInstance (http://localhost:3000/code-challenge-test/static/js/vendors-node_modules_msw_lib_browser_index_mjs-node_modules_msw_lib_core_HttpResponse_mjs-nod-735fa5.chunk.js:2616:11)
at async startWorkerInstance (http://localhost:3000/code-challenge-test/static/js/vendors-node_modules_msw_lib_browser_index_mjs-node_modules_msw_lib_core_HttpResponse_mjs-nod-735fa5.chunk.js:3496:24)
at async SetupWorkerApi.start (http://localhost:3000/code-challenge-test/static/js/vendors-node_modules_msw_lib_browser_index_mjs-node_modules_msw_lib_core_HttpResponse_mjs-nod-735fa5.chunk.js:4723:12)

it needs to work both on local with mocks and on github pages, is this possible ?
